# Spring Security пользователь по умолчанию

Tags: java, spring, безопасность, spring-security, spring-boot

У меня в системе должен быть один глобальный администратор, который может управлять другими пользователями ( в моем контексте - редакторы). 
Существует две роли ROLE_ADMIN и ROLE_EDITOR.

Как правильно создать и хранить этого пользователя?

1. Добавить его в базу данных в момент развертывания приложения. Создать пустую базу и в SQL руками прописать создание двух ролей и одного администратора.
2. Хранить логин и пароль админа в property и в UserDetailService простым ифом выдавать админа, а редакторов хранить в бд.

Или есть какое-то правильное решение?

Comment: Они оба правильные. Тут дело вкуса. Единственное пароль в чистом виде не стоит хранить. Лучше хранить его хеш. Плюс во втором случае надо будет предусмотреть возможность смены пароля.

Comment: @Темкатоже, а можно ли прописать инициализацию в CommandLineRunner? А брать информацию с property.

Comment: что ты подразумеваешь под CommandLineRunner?

Comment: @Темкатоже интерфейс Spring. Запускается при запуске приложения.

Comment: если это часть `spring boot`, то ничего сказать не могу